# Verify that object is shared in memory between Ruby Unicorn processes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, unicorn

I do `FOO = MyBigImmutableObject.new("my.db")` in a Ruby on Rails initializer, building a ~60 MB object.

My assumption is that this happens before the Unicorn app server forks, and that this means it only uses 60 MB once, not once per worker process.

How can I verify this, though? I've tried looking at the memory usage for Unicorn using `ps`, but that shows a 60 MB increase for every worker process when I introduce this constant. So I'm thinking maybe it doesn't distinguish shared memory in a way that helps me with this.

Checking total used/free memory on the system seems tricky since I would have to isolate everything else.

What are some good ways for me to verify that it's shared in memory?

Comment: I don't think Ruby shares memory between processes.

Comment: @Stefan My impression is that newer (than 2.0 or thereabouts) versions of Ruby can rely on the underlying *ux system to get copy-on-write memory with forked processes, meaning that forked processes can share memory with their parent process until it changes in one of the child processes (then it's duplicated in memory before it's changed). But this is outside my area of expertise, thus my asking :) If you know more, please do set me straight.

Comment: I see what you mean. But that's nothing Unicorn does, it's the way Ruby works. Unicorn has a `before_fork` hook. You could use that to check whether your object has already been initialized at that point.

Comment: @Stefan Thank you. I didn't mean to suggest this was unique to Unicorn, only to give context :) I tried checking in `before_fork` and it was indeed initialized. I also just tried using `smem` as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/323736/129926, looking at the "USS" value to represent "unshared memory", and that number did indeed not go up for the workers (or the master, strangely) when doing it pre-fork, but it did go up for the workers when I tried doing it in `after_fork`.

Comment: That's strange indeed. Is the object's initialization process asynchronous in some way? Or maybe it is actually not immutable. Try to replace it with a 60 MB frozen string and see what happens.